# Concourse - version is missing from previous step while build docker image

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-resource-types

**Goal:** Build a continuous integration pipeline for a spring boot application that runs JUnit tests, packages, builds a docker image, and finally pushes that image to Amazon Elastic Container Registry.

The pipeline that I have built is able to run the maven test phase, run maven package, but then complains while executing the task for building the docker image.

Below is a screenshot of the pipeline.

[image: concourse pipeline]

As you can see the build-and-push job partially fails. Below is the screenshot of tasks contained inside the build-and-push job.

[image: buil-and-push-tasks-list]

And we see the error **version is missing from the previous step.**

My pipeline looks like this

```
resources:
  - name: session-management-service-repo
    type: git
    icon: github
    source:
      branch: develop
      uri: ((source_url))
      username: ((myusername))
      password: ((mypassowrd)

  - name: ecr-docker-reg
    type: registry-image
    icon: docker
    source:
      aws_access_key_id: ((access_key_id))
      aws_secret_access_key: ((secret_access_key))
      aws_region: ((region))
      repository: srm-session-management-service
      tag: latest

resource_types:
  - name: registry-image
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: registry:5000/srm/registry-image-resource
      insecure_registries:
        - registry:5000

jobs:
  - name: test
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: session-management-service-repo
        trigger: true
      - task: mvn-test-task
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/maven-test.yml

  - name: build-and-push
    public: true
    serial: true
    plan:
      - get: session-management-service-repo
        trigger: true
        passed: [test]
      - task: mvn-package-task
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/maven-package.yml
      - task: build-image-task
        privileged: true # oci-build-task must run in a privileged container
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/build-image.yml
      - put: ecr-docker-reg
        params: {image: image/image.tar}
```

Here I have built a custom resource type that is extended from concourse/registry-image-resource. Basically, I wanted to include some certificates in the resource so that it does not face any problem while uploading the image to ECR as I run behind a proxy. So, the docker file for this custom resource looks like below. I build the image from this dockerfile and push the image running on the same server where the concourse is running, thus in a private docker registry. Later in the pipeline, as you can see I pull this resource type from the custom docker registry...check **ecr-docker-reg** in the resources section. (This is what I am trying to do.)

```
FROM concourse/registry-image-resource

ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@myhost:port
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@myhost:port
ARG NO_PROXY=localhost,*.myhost.com,127.0.0.1,.myhost.com

ENV http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY}
ENV no_proxy=${NO_PROXY}
ENV HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=${HTTPS_PROXY}
ENV NO_PROXY=${NO_PROXY}

COPY certificates/Cert-CA-bundle.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

#RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl
```

The maven package task and the accompanying script looks like this

```
---
platform: linux
image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: maven
inputs:
  - name: session-management-service-repo
run:
  path: /bin/sh
  args: ["./session-management-service-repo/ci/scripts/maven-package.sh"]
outputs:
  - name: session-management-service-repo-out
```

maven package script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
mvn -version
cd session-management-service-repo
cp -f ci/assets/maven/settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
cp -a * ../session-management-service-repo-out
```

And the build-image-task looks like this

```
---
platform: linux
image_resource:
  type: registry-image
  source:
    repository: concourse/oci-build-task
inputs:
  - name: session-management-service-repo-out
outputs:
  - name: image
params:
  CONTEXT: session-management-service-repo-out
run:
  path: build
```

---

**Note:**
One thing to note here is that this error that I started to get is when I used my custom resource type. Before using my custom resource type I did not face this **"version is missing from previous step"** error, rather it was something like below which I only got while pushing the docker image and not while building the image, so I was successfully able to build the image. But as you can see that it the certificate error, I therefore decided to use custom resource type that has the needed certificates included.

```
selected worker: 1b0fd33bcd2b
WARN[0000] ECR integration is experimental and untested 
ERRO[0000] failed to authenticate to ECR: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority 
ERRO[0000] cannot authenticate with ECR
```

My pipeline before using custom resource type was almost similar, just that it did not contain the resource_types section

```
resources:
  - name: session-management-service-repo
    type: git
    icon: github
    source:
      branch: develop
      uri: ((source_url))
      username: ((myusername))
      password: ((mypassword))

  - name: ecr-docker-reg
    type: registry-image
    icon: docker
    source:
      aws_access_key_id: ((access_key))
      aws_secret_access_key: ((secret_access_key))
      aws_region: ((region))
      repository: srm-session-management-service
      tag: latest

jobs:
  - name: test
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: session-management-service-repo
        trigger: true
      - task: mvn-test-task
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/maven-test.yml

  - name: build-and-push
    public: true
    serial: true
    plan:
      - get: session-management-service-repo
        trigger: true
        passed: [test]
      - task: mvn-package-task
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/maven-package.yml
      - task: build-image-task
        privileged: true # oci-build-task must run in a privileged container
        file: session-management-service-repo/ci/tasks/build-image.yml
      - put: ecr-docker-reg
        params: {image: image/image.tar}
```

I am not able to figure out what am I missing or where am I going wrong. Any suggestion would be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double check your resource types and make sure they have the right image and tag, you can pull them, and concourse can pull them

Answer (score 0):

In my experience resolving this in production systems,
I have found that this message more often occures due to your requested `tag: latest` does not exist in the provided registry location `repository: srm-session-management-service`.

I would:

1. use the concourse UI's [image] button to confirm the failure is indeed happening on a `get: image` step
2. identify which image is being retrieved, based on the specific failing one (match it to your pipeline yaml file)
3. triple check if the tag actually exists as intended (it may be something like `prod`, `v1.0`, `release` as the `latest` tag usually needs to be explicitly added and is not a default fallback provided in registries).

Looking into your specific case, I see the image pull within the `build-image` task doesn't specify a tag, only referencing it by name.  Does this registry use version tags, and can you add such a tag to this task?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `version` property instead of `tag` here:

```
 - name: ecr-docker-reg
type: registry-image
icon: docker
source:
  aws_access_key_id: ((access_key_id))
  aws_secret_access_key: ((secret_access_key))
  aws_region: ((region))
  repository: srm-session-management-service
  **version: latest**
```

Comment: https://github.com/concourse/registry-image-resource#source-configuration literally says 'tag' not 'version'

Comment: Depending on the version you use, `version` may be appropriated: https://github.com/concourse/registry-image-resource/tree/v1.0.0#parameters-1